# two servers have linked to the same server - one connection is encrypted and second not - why?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have some old SQL Server 2008r2 instances that do not have client certificate set up and force encryption is set to FALSE.

It is on Windows 2008 r2 and really hard to upgrade - for now it must stay as it is.

I have 2 virtual machines that have SQL Server 2019 installed (Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU19) (KB5023049) - 15.0.4298.1 (X64)).

Both of them have same settings - `FORCE ENCRYPTION SET TO TRUE` etc
both have same TLS settings
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qzrq.png]
i think not relevant but just in cause

Both have the same linked server definition

```sql
     EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'PB01', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
     EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'PB01',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser='SOMEUSER',@rmtpassword='SOMEUSERPASS'
     EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
     EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'PB01', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
```

When I'm using this linkedservers to the 2008 r2 instance from both sql 2019 servers do some query that uses this linked `PB01` - works FINE

When I run:

```
    SELECT client_net_address,
    c.session_id, c.net_transport, c.encrypt_option, 
    c.auth_scheme, s.host_name, s.program_name, 
    s.client_interface_name, s.login_name, s.nt_domain, 
    s.nt_user_name, s.original_login_name, c.connect_time, 
    s.login_time 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS c
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
    ON c.session_id = s.session_id
```

I see that from the first 2019 server instance - encrypt_option = true
and for second 2019 server instance - encrypt_option = false

**So the question is::**

Why/how is that possible? Whats more can is I do so from both it is encrypt_option to be = `true`?  i need it to be `true` from both 2019 servers.

Is there any other thing that can be game changing option here?

Comment: What Windows versions are the SQL Server 2019 servers?

Comment: Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763 both

Comment: Specify `@provstr = 'provider_string'` in the `sp_addlinkedserver` command and the string should contain the usual parameters as well as `Encrypt=True`

Comment: yes i known but this reqire using other provider - native client / ole - using simple @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' does not allow encrypt true cause it does not have any provider string option. To be honest i known that on that linked server provider it should not encrypt i think. but why it is doing it / what forces that on this setup ? tls may force this somehow?